# Confused about the solution to the pendulum differential equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, calculus, differential-equations, angular-velocity

So I’ve learned how to derive the exact solution to the pendulum differential equation (in respect to its period), $\ddot{\theta} + \frac{g}{l}\sin\theta=0$, where $g$ is gravitational acceleration and  $l$ is the length of the string attached to the pendulum. [The solution turns out to be](https://youtu.be/efvT2iUSjaA):
$$T = 4\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}K\left(\sin{\left(\frac{\theta_0}2\right)}\right),$$

Where $\theta_0$ is the starting angle of the pendulum, and $K(k)$ is the Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind, which can be expressed as:
$$K(k) = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{d\eta}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\eta}}$$

If you set $\theta_0 = 0, K\left(\sin{\left(\frac{\theta_0}2\right)}\right) = \frac{\pi}2$, which would make $T = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}$. But this doesn’t make sense—how could the period be equal to anything other than $0$? If $\theta_0 = 0$, the pendulum isn’t in motion!

Comment: I have edited your question to include what I think are better tags;  feel free to revert this if you don't like them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the derivation of the period, it is implicitly assumed that $\theta_0 \neq 0$.  Specifically, the standard derivation via energy conservation leads to the integral
$$
T = 2 \sqrt{\frac{l}g} \int_0^{\theta_0} \frac{d \theta}{\sqrt{\sin^2 (\theta_0/2) - \sin^2(\theta/2)}} 
$$
If $\theta_0 = 0$, then this integral is obviously zero.  But to put this in the form you're using above for an elliptic integral, we then need to make the substitution $$\sin \eta = \frac{\sin(\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta_0/2)},$$ which is not a valid operation when $\theta_0 = 0$.

Comment: Oh! That makes sense, thank you! Is it possible to put that integral in the form of any elliptic integrals (including incomplete ones)?

Comment: @Mailbox:  You mean the integral when $\theta_0 = 0$?  Probably not (or at least in any way that's interesting);  it's equal to zero by definition because of the limits of integration.

Comment: Hello again! I looked into this a little more myself, and I’m not sure this answer fully explains the problem for when $\theta_0 = 0$. 
Firstly, when $\theta_0 = 0$, the integral above does not equal zero—it becomes undefined. Second, if we take the limit as $\theta \to 0$, the integral converges to $\pi$, leaving us with the same problem as before: $T$ converges to $2\pi\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}$, which is still nonsensical even when considering limits. How could a pendulum have such a large period when its starting angle is infinitesimally small?

Comment: @Mailbox Concerning your second point, that's the point of the small-angle approximation:  in the limit of small oscillations, the pendulum becomes a harmonic oscillator with a period independent of the amplitude.  Roughly speaking, this is because at small displacements the restoring torque is correspondingly small (in fact, it's approximately linear), so for a small displacement there's very little force pushing it back towards equilibrium.

Comment: As to the first point, yeah, I suppose that it's probably better to take that integral as undefined.  But if we go back a step or two in the derivation, the period is defined as the amount of time required to go from maximum displacement $\theta = \theta_0$ to the equilibrium position $\theta = 0$.  If $\theta_0 = 0$, I don't see how this quantity can be anything other than zero.

Answer (score 0):

A constant function has any period. i.e. you cannot write a lowest period and so it is not a meaningful quantity.

Comment: There are varying definitions of the elliptic integral — the integral that some sources call $K(x)$ is called $K(x^2)$ by other sources.  So that's not necessarily wrong.

Comment: I just realised this- my mistake! I think that the question is right (have edited it out of my answer).